What is the mean of the stochastic differential equation $dX=K dt + \sigma X dW$ and how to find it?
I have the stochastic differential equation, $$dX=k dt + \sigma XdW,$$
which I expect to have just the mean $kt$, since taking the expectation of the SDE gives E[dX]=E[k dt] due to the brownian term and $x$ being uncorrelated. However, when I define y=ln(x) instead and use Ito calculus to find the SDE for y, it leads me to the equation, $$dY=(k e^{-y}-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})dt+\sigma dW,$$ which gives a completely different solution for the mean, $$E[x]=\frac{2k+e^{-t \sigma^2/2} (-2 k + \sigma^2 e^{ln(x0)})}{\sigma^2}.$$ What is the reason for this discrepancy or what am I doing wrong?

Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

It is a version of the geometric Brownian motion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion (bur with a simple drift rather than the usual exponential relaxation). https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746826/226902

I am getting even more confused. I was trying to play around with the simple stochastic differential equation $dX=X\sigma dW$. Again, Ito's calculus suggests the solution $X(t)=X(0)e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} t} e^{\sigma W_t}$ which suggests that as $t->\infty$, $X(t)$ approaches zero which indeed a simple simulation code confirms. Alternatively, you can solve this system using an integrating factor $e^{-\sigma W_t}$, doing so, you will find $X(t)=X(0) e^{\sigma W_t}$, which does not behave the same as the previous result, but I also don't know why it is wrong. Any ideas?

I will answer your comment before turning to your main question:
For your first result: $X(t)=X(0)e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} t} e^{\sigma W_t}$. The average of $e^{\sigma W_t}$ is $e^{\sigma^2 t/2}$. This follows directly from the gaussian average of a gaussian. Thus $\langle X(t) \rangle = X(0)$ as expected from the fact that $dX =X\sigma dW\Rightarrow \langle dX\rangle =0$ IF the stochastic equation is interpreted with Ito prescription. With Ito prescription, the stochastic process is non anticipating, hence $\langle X dW\rangle=\langle X\rangle\langle dW\rangle$.
This is at odd with your second result $X(t)=X(0)e^{\sigma W_t}\Rightarrow \langle X(t)\rangle=X(0)e^{\sigma^2 t/2}$ (diverges). Because, by using an integrating factor, you assumed that chain rules, usual integration, etc... worked for the stochastic equation. This is fine, but in this case, you are using Stratonovich convention. With this convention for example $\langle X dW\rangle\neq\langle X\rangle\langle dW\rangle$ (because of a peculiar discretization).
So! To recapitulate. Your problem comes from the fact that $dX=X\sigma dW$ is ill defined as it is. You have to give it a prescription. Be it Ito, which is useful to evaluate mean values because of the non anticipating property of the stochastic process. Or Stratonovich (which is useful if you want to carelessly apply the usual differential calculus rules). Both your solutions are "right" but only when the equations are interpreted accordingly. I suggest you read p. 41 Stochastic energetics by K. Sekimoto. It discusses exactly this issue and how to convert an equation with Stratonovich convention to one with Ito convention. And gives some more details.

The exact same thing happens for your question. In the main part you first evaluate your equation the Ito way and the second time, you use regular calculus, integration, etc. Which leads to a Stratonovich result.
See for example my lazy computation of the mean value from Mathematica. Here is with Stratonovich convention.

And here is with Ito:


Edit, partial answer to your comment concerning the interpretation of the equations: I'm extremely rusty and it will be only a partial answer. I am also coming from the physics community side, maybe these questions have been clarified differently in the math literature.
Indeed, knowing which prescription to use is a very difficult question. Notably, it was an issue during the 60s where people started just writing down a Langevin equation by using a deterministic part and simply adding on top of it a noise. The deterministic part needs somehow to be measured. But from this measurement, you just obtain (or guess) the "non fluctuating" part, by itself, this part can contain contributions from the fluctuations. Hence, it's not trivial to simply guess what a Langevin equation for a given problem. An extremely influential physicist named Van Kamped argued that you simply should not write any non linear langevin equation (in general) out of your head, because you generally don't have any direct way to verify if the equation is correct or not. He instead argued that, if one wants still to define a Langevin equation, you have to derive it from an expansion of a Master equation, which gives a Fokker-Plank equation which then can be used to write down the langevin equation that would lead to this Fokker Plank equation (note that it requires markoviannity, gaussiannity, ...). All of this to tell that it's a hard question. Now, I don't know what you know about stochastic calculus, so I'll might say things you already know.
At a "fundamental level" there is a difference between the Ito prescription and the Stratonovich one because the noise is singular/delta correlated. For example, with inertia, the noise for the position becomes exponentially correlated and you don't have to deal with this non-sense of prescription anymore... In fact Ito does not make really any sense when your noise is time correlated. Let's see why by writing naively a general non linear multiplicative stochastic differential equation:
$$d X = - F(X) dt + C(X) dW$$
Due to the singularity of the Wiener process, $dW$ is of order $\sqrt{dt}$:  $dW\sim \mathcal N(0, dt)$.
This leads to things that, in usual calculus, you would not care about.
Ito discretization
Let's write the discretization explicitly (i call that Ito discretization for reasons that will become clear later):
$$X(t+dt)-X(t) = - F(X(t)) dt + C(X(t)) (W(t+dt)-W(t))$$
If you take the mean value:
$$\langle X(t+dt)-X(t)\rangle = - \langle F(X(t))\rangle dt + \underbrace{\langle C(X(t)) (W(t+dt)-W(t))\rangle}_{\langle C(X(t)) \rangle\langle(W(t+dt)-W(t))\rangle=0}$$
Where the last mean is 0 because $X(t)$ is uncorrelated to $W(t)$ and $W(t+dt)$. This is what we call the Ito Interpretation and more importantly, the non-anticipating property of Ito calculus. The process at $t$ is supposed to be uncorrelated with the noise at this same instant. You see somehow, that this is a bit strange, or at least something that could only arise when the noise is delta correlated and hence singular.
But, we can also do a different discretization.
Stratonovich discretization
$$X(t+dt)-X(t) = - F(X(t)) dt + C\left(\frac{X(t) + X(t+dt)}{2}\right) (W(t+dt)-W(t))$$
That is, you evaluate the function at a different instant. In regular calculus, this would not change a thing because the difference between this descritization (in front of a regular differential) and the Ito one would be of order $dt^2$. But here, $X(t)+X(t+dt)$ has term of order $\sqrt{dt}$ exactly like $dW$ so that, in the end, a contribution of order $\sqrt{dt}\times \sqrt{dt}$ appears and must be taken into account! You also see that now:
$$\left\langle C\left(\frac{X(t) + X(t+dt)}{2}\right) (W(t+dt)-W(t))\right\rangle \neq\left\langle C\left(\frac{X(t) + X(t+dt)}{2}\right)\right\rangle\langle (W(t+dt)-W(t))\rangle $$
Because the function is evaluated at a "mid point" (I like to see it as evaluated at $t + dt/2$, but it's completely false mathematically and physically, it's just neat intellectually) and its value depends on the value at $t$.
Ito vs Stratonovich
You see now that the equation:
$$d X = - F(X) dt + C(X) dW$$
is ill defined as it is. Because contributions of order $dt$ appears according to the discretization used (there exists more that two, you can very well do $(1-\alpha) X(t) + \alpha X(t+dt)$ with $\alpha\in[0, 1]$). You also got the idea that different prescriptions lead to different rules, here I just gave them for mean values but you also have different rules for calculus, as you already know. Be careful though to something important. From the equation I gave, you might thing that the Ito vs Stratonovich is something that you really don't have to care about if $C(X)$ is independent on $X$. That partially the case, but even in this case, you must be consistent in your interpretation. If you have the equation: $d X = - F(X) dt + dW$ and want to compute $\langle X(t) dW/dt \rangle$, this thing will have different values whether you decide to use an Ito approach (where it's equal to 0) or a Stratonovich approach. For example, take the equation for an overdamped brownian particle:
$$dx = \sqrt{2D}dW$$
There is not Ito vs Stratonovich confusion here because the noise is not multiplicative! BUT! You still must be consistent in the rules of calculus you use and thus, in the interpretation. For example if you want to compute $d\langle x^2\rangle/dt$, you can either assume that the chain rule is correct (SO NOT USING ITO FORMULA FOR THE CHAIN RULE!) but in this case, you must compute non trivial things related to $\langle x \dot x\rangle\sim \langle x dW/dt\rangle$ which are non zero in Stratonovich approach. Or you can either go the Ito way, and use the Ito chain rule (that you used in your post), in which case, the mean values are trivial to evaluate. But again, and this is very important both approaches will give the same result because the equation does not have a multiplicative noise, and is thus insensitive to the prescription used. Here, Ito vs Stratonovich is just a fight for a computational method.
See these notes for crystal clear information of what I just tried to explain.
Partial Answer to your comment
Now, with a multiplicative noise, the physics will be different. We often say that Stratonovich leads to a Spurious drift. Indeed, take again this equation:
$$d X = - F(X) dt + C(X) dW$$
The associated Fokker-Plank equation for the probability  $P(x)$ will be in Ito case:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(F(x) \right)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 (C(x)^2P)}{\partial x^2}$$
and in Statonovich case:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(F(x) + \frac{1}{2}C(x)C'(x)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 (C(x)^2P)}{\partial x^2}$$
You see here, that for Stratonovich interpretation you obtained a "drift" proportional to $CC'$ (vanishing in the case of non multiplicative noise) which was present in your equation in you comment under your post.
Thus, from data alone, you can guess the correct prescription for Langevin equation from the Fokker Plank equation. If you see a drift for example, while you are pretty sure that the """""""deterministic"""""""" (force) part cannot cause that.
To get back to what I was saying earlier, if you write down a Langevin equation with delta correlated noise on top of your head and wonder what kind of interpretation to give it. If the noise is external, most of the time, you have to interpret it the Stratonovich way because, Stratonivch is the natural interpretation (the only reall) when the autocorrelation of the noise is non 0 (not delta correlated). Which is more or less always true in this kind of system. Then, the confusion arises because, you take the limit of a very small autocorrelation time (smaller than all time scales in your system) and then, in this case, the dilemna of ito vs strato arises. But originally, the equations had a finite correlation time $\tau$ which had to be interpreted in the Stratonovich way (because Ito does not exist since the noise is not singular), and in the limit $\tau\to 0$, the equation still has to be interpreted in Stratonovich way. More formally, if you have an equation:
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=F(X(t)) + C(X(t))\eta(t) ~~~\text{with}~~~ \langle \eta(0)\eta(t)\rangle=\kappa_{\tau}(t)$$
With $\tau$ a correlation time, for example: $\kappa_\tau(t) = e^{-t/\tau}/\tau$. If $\kappa_{\tau\to 0}=\delta(t)$, the equation with $\tau\to 0$ can be proven to follow a Stratonovich prescription.
But, again! You could rewrite this equation so that it follows Ito prescription (by adding a counter drift). It would be an equation with different symbols but it would have the same physics. It does not make much sense to say that a process has to be interpreted in Ito or Stratonovich way. It's more something like: What prescription leads to an equation that is the simplest and with the clearest meaning just by looking at the symbols, but you can convert equations from one prescription to an other without any issue.
To come back at how to chose a noise. If the noise is internal, the things are a bit more tricky, and in general, you must derive your Langevin equation from a master equation but sometimes, you can solve the issue directly from the discretization definition of the prescription:
Let's imagine a radioactive decay process. You have $N$ particles that can each decay at a poissonian rate $\gamma$. The deterministic equation must be:
$$dN/dt = -\gamma N$$
If you write down this thing, you are working at the macroscopic level. At a finer scale, you will see some stochasticity which must be dealt with trhough a master equation, but let's say that you want to shortcut the rigorous math, you will write a noise term, it will be itself proportional to the number of particles (you will have more fluctuations with more particles), let's also assume a central limit scaling of this noise such that its variance is proportional to $N$:
$$dN(t)/dt = -\gamma N(t) + \sqrt{N(t)}\eta(t)$$
well... How should you interpret it? Ito way or Stratonovich way? The noise arise due to stochastic decay. The decay is proportional to the number of particles before the decay not after (of course...), thus you have some kind of non-anticipation. The realization of the noise at some given time is really uncorrelated with the number of particle at the same time because it arises DUE to the decay at this instant.
Everything I said can be more or less found in Sec IX of the book by Van Kampen.

Thank you! In my second result, I thought I am evaluating everything the Ito way. What I did was to write the SDE for $ln(x)$ using Ito's formula, and then again use Ito's way to find $<d(ln(X))>=(\frac{k}{x} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})dt+<\sigma dW>=(\frac{k}{x} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})dt$, and solving the differential equation for $E(ln(x))$ then use it to find x=Exp(E(ln(x))). I sense that my last step is the problem since $E(ln(x)) \neq ln(E(x))$. Is that right?

One more thing, how should I interpret the different mean results? So, after solving the differential equation with either convention and having a nice function for the mean, they still show different mean dynamics, how is that and how are they equivalent when comparing the mean dynamics?

Concerning your first comment, indeed if you found the mean this way it is a problem. It is strange though that it leads to the Stratonovich result. Maybe there's something deeper to get here! Any way, I'll add an edit to my answer later today to partially answer your question in the comment.

I edited my answer

Notice that my way did not lead to the Stratonovich result as mine asymptotes to a constant while your solution grows exponentially.

Ah yes, indeed I read that too quickly and was really onto the idea that the issues in your comment and in the main question were the same!
